# Terminate parent method from child method

Tags: c#

I create a plugin for an application.
When a user presses a stop command in the parent application, a global variable to which my plugin has access to is set to true.
For a simple method I create, I test this variable and exit:

```
public class Status
{
    public static bool CheckTermFlag()
    {
        if (VoiceAttackPlugin._stopVariableToMonitor)
        {
            VoiceAttackPlugin._stopVariableToMonitor = false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I place this 'CheckTermFlag' in my code:

```
class ForTesting
{
    public static void SendStopAllTest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            if (Status.CheckTermFlag())
            {
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            vaProxy.WriteToLog(i.ToString(), "Green");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I may have several methods and each calling another one.
I can't place a question for "Status.CheckTermFlag()" in every step of my program and propagate it upwards.

So how can i 'listen' for this variable from anywhere in my program and terminate/return if required?

Comment: I would think you will have to check for that value every time you call a method to see if the state has changed, being C# it's difficult to have that active listener. Another option is to have a while loop with a yield return to make it slower and a break to step out of the loop and then just actively checking that value every few seconds but it's dangerous working with an infinite loop like that.

Comment: How about events?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.1) for this? You can stop any method by any method that way. If a method have access to `CTS` it can just call `Cancel` and all methods that have `CancellationToken`s can then finish whatever they are doing and exit.

In multithreading environment a [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1) can be used as an awaitable reset event as a mean of synchronizing threads.

I wouldn't use `Thread.Abort()`, it's good for the threads you have no control over. But if it's all your code and you control it - it's always better just to signal between threads and ask them nicely to terminate, that leads to less undefined states and behaviors later.

BTW, just make either the `CancellationTokenSource` accessible to methods that should stop the calling method, or made an accessible method that calls `Cancel()` on `CTS`. I used that approach a lot in a high-load network gateway and a desktop application that downloaded a large number of files parallelly. The cost of it is negligible. Don't be afraid of disposables, used correctly they save more time than it takes to handle them.

Comment: from the little I read about CancellationTokenSource  so far notices that i have to ask or set them as well.
I mean that I should set  source.Cancel(); everywhere i see fit.
it is still not done in one place, correct?

Comment: You can have one source signalling to all tokens. It's just a program that issues a kind of pointers to its own state. It's thread safe, so you can call `Cancel()` from many threads, any thread using token will see the cancellation is requested. You can also have multiple sources for multiple tasks. After signalling the source should be disposed and then created again if needed. Let's say all child threads should stop when user cancels the complex action, or the main process should stop if any child process fails. In that case - 2 sources are needed. One for each direction.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-threaded scenario the way to go is the [`Thread.Abort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) method. It throws the [`ThreadAbortException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception) in the target thread, causing it to terminate.

If you, for whatever reason, need a custom solution, do it likewise. Throw an exception, and handle it at the top-most method where it makes sense. Like this:

```
public class TerminateProcessingExeption : Exception { … }

…

public static bool CheckTermFlag()
{
    if (VoiceAttackPlugin._stopVariableToMonitor)
    {
        VoiceAttackPlugin._stopVariableToMonitor = false;
        throw new TerminateProcessingExeption();
    }
}
```

In addition, instead of a `bool` flag, consider using an `AutoResetEvent`. Look into the example [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent) for more information. A simple variable won't shield you from the adverse effects of concurrent memory access in multi-processor setups.

Comment: Thanks, 
For you proposal I should create these threads, correct?
I'm still learning C#...
I'll look into threads.

Comment: @dandan Well, your question lets me assume a multi-threaded scenario. If not, consider clarifying your question with a more complete picture of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dandan Regardless of that, the answer to the “propagate it upwards” part of your question is “throw an exception”. Exceptions do have this capability.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for you reply and I'll try to clarify. 
My C# plugin is being invoked by an application - VoicerAttck which I do not control it.
In my plugin I may call methods which may call several other methods and at any time the user may press "STOP".
When "STOP" is pressed, in VoiceAttack,it sets a certain global variable "_isStop" to "true".
My plugin can read the value of this variable any any time and when I detect it is "true" I want to terminate all the actions my plugin is doing.

I could add an if(_isStop) ...  in every method, every few lines but I'm sure there is a netter way.

Comment: So I want to know if I can create a process (don't know how to to this) which will monitor _isStop variable an when this is 'true' return the control to the parent application - VoiceAttack and reset _isStop to false.
I'm trying to avoid inserting a query about _isStop in various methods.

@Ondrej_Tuncny